# How to add new button using t-extend?

Tags: javascript, jquery, odoo-8, odoo-10, odoo

I want to add a new button "Update" after button "delete". I have tried to extend the t-name but it is not reflecting on UI.

**Source code:**

```
<t t-name="Export.SavedList">
    <label>Saved exports: </label>
    <select class="o_exported_lists_select">
    <option></option>
    <t t-foreach="existing_exports" t-as="export">
        <option t-att-value="export.id"><t t-esc="export.name"/></option>
    </t>
    </select>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default 
o_delete_exported_list">Delete</button>
</t>
```

**I have Tried to extend source and add new button after "delete" as given in Source:**

```
<template>
<t t-extend="web.Export.SavedList">
<t t-jquery="button.btn btn-sm btn-default o_delete_exported_list" t-operation="after">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">Update</button>
</t>
</t>
</template>
```

It is not working. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this fix in the second line

```
<template>
  <t t-extend="Export.SavedList"><!-- THIS LINE -->
    <t t-jquery="button.btn btn-sm btn-default o_delete_exported_list" t-operation="after">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">Update</button>
    </t>
  </t>
</template>
```